# Parsing a table with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I feel like I must be so close on this one but I cant seem to identify the right table name to get the data from. Could someone take a quick look at this and tell me where I am going wrong? Pretty sure I am currently getting no data back from the table variable?

```
def oddsmath

   require 'nokogiri'


   tables_data = []

   doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.oddsmath.com/odds-comparison/"))

  doc.css('table#table-odds-comparison.tbl-odds-comparison.tablesorter.tablesorter-default.hasStickyHeaders').each do |table|

# find all rows in the current table, then iterate over the second all the way to the final one...
table.css('tr')[1..-1].each do |tr|

# collect the cell data and raw names from the remaining rows' cells...
raw_name = tr.at('th').text
cell_data = tr.css('td').map(&:text)

# aggregate it...
tables_data += [raw_name, cell_data]
end
end
@output=tables_data

end
```

Comment: Why is there a space in `"http://www.oddsmath.com/odds- comparison/"`?

Comment: Can you describe in English how to uniquely identify the table you want?

Comment: Hi Mark, It's the main table on that page - the odds comparison table - should brink back the following fields date, league, type, home team, 1(2),X(2), 2(2), Away Team, Margin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the actual HTML returned when you visit that page, you'll see the table is actually empty, and the contents are dynamically loaded by JS.  Because of that you can't do what you want with just nokogiri opening the page. You'll need to use something that allows you to control a real browser (or emulates a browser with JS support) in order for the page to fully load before getting the page contents, or you'll need to figure out what URL the page is loading the data for the table from and see if you can access it directly from there (may not be possible).

Comment: Good spot - you are right! I was looking at the inspect element view rather than show the page source. It's in the former but not in the latter.

Comment: @John - Correct, because the inspect element view shows the current status of the page as affected by all JS that has been run.  If you want to see all the raw documents/data the browser loads you can look at the network tab in the developer console of the console.